Is there a way to decrease MJML code output to avoid being clipped by Gmail?
Our client uses really lengthy emails. As you know MJML code output can be pretty lengthy, which results in our client emails being clipped by Gmail because they go over the 102kb limit before an email gets clipped.
I managed to lower this amount by minifying the email but the email is still about 132kb sized on average.
Is there a way to decrease the amount even further? Maybe some custom components that don't use as much code as <mj-section> and <mj-column>?
Our emails are important to look good on these email providers: Gmail, GMX, Web.de and Outlook.
I tried minifying the file and this decreases the size of the email for about 30% percent on average.
Also, replaced as many elements as possible with an image block.

Once you're optimising like this, you're looking at full custom code. It's one of the drawbacks of using systems like this. MJML is optimised to be the most flexible it can be, so you'll be fighting it every step of the way. You'll need to create your own components, essentially, and probably outside of MJML.
